# SslStream .read() returns with first byte once a packet

Tags: c#, sockets, websocket

I want to read packets from my SslStream.

I send the packets using websocket. Also, this function is started after i finished the WS Handshake so it is for reading data frames.

This is the function for reading:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
int read;
while (true) {
    read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    Console.WriteLine("Length: " + read + " Buffer: " + GetNumberOfSlotsUsed(buffer));

    if (read <= 0) {
        ...
    } else if (read < 3) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Once i receive a packet, this is what gets printed out to the console:

```
Length: 1 Buffer: 1
Length: 57 Buffer: 57
```

Can the problem be in this function or is it the Browser which sends the packets?

I use the "socket.read()" function in my Websocket Server written in Java and there is no problem, so it must be C# right?

Edit #1:

Javascript code for sending:

```
var socket = new WebSocket(serviceUrl, protocol);
socket.onopen = function () {
    socket.send(omeString);
}
```

Comment: *"it is for reading data frames"*, C#'s `Stream.Read` function is not guaranteed to read a entire frame per `Read` call, you must reconstruct the frame first. However, getting a size of 1 is weird, how are you declaring `buffer`?

Comment: Can you show the sending code too? It's ok that it is in another language. in fact if you do `<!-- language: java -->` before the code block it will switch the code highlighting from C# to Java for that block.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Edited. Thanks for the hint. Also Java isn't the client. I meant that I also programmed a websocket server in Java where the "read" part is the "same" as in C#. If i could determine which bytes go together, it wouldn't mind that they get split.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For future people searching for this exact same issue:

I have found an article explaining that this odd occurrence is by design.

This seems like an odd thing to call a "Feature." Basically (as i understand it) this change was to make SslStream Read and Write the first byte and then push the rest. I personally think that this is an odd change. Kinda weird to force multiple packets of transfer. (I am fully aware that this could happen, its just odd to force an additional packet on top of a possibility that packets could be segmented.)

[Link to Article](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2590316/windows-10-update-kb3147458-changes-behavior-of-sslstream-read-beginread-endread)

---

Posted by **Nimbus.Hex**

```
When ran on machine updated with KB3147458, this output is produced:
BytesRead => 1
BytesRead => 40
BytesRead => 1
BytesRead => 40
BytesRead => 1
BytesRead => 40
BytesRead => 1
BytesRead => 40
BytesRead => 1
BytesRead => 40

When ran on a machine without KB3147458, this output is produced:
BytesRead => 41
BytesRead => 41
BytesRead => 41
BytesRead => 41
BytesRead => 41
```

---

Posted by **Ilia Jerebtsov**

> I would guess that this is more specifically caused by KB3142037,
>   which is a security update for MS16-065. The issues herein and a few
>   workarounds are detailed at
>   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3155464 . There are registry
>   keys that can be used to disable this "feature".

---

Posted by **Microsoft**:

> Hi Nimbus.Hex, Yes Ilia is correct. This is a behavioral change done
>   for security update for MS16-065. There are more details around the
>   change available at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3155464 . I
>   resolving this as "By Design" Regards, Himadri

Comment: Thank you for extending this. Back then i thought packets are only sent as "one" which added to the confusion.

Comment: You are very welcome! Was having a similar issue and thought Id share my findings in the hopes that the next person researching the topic runs into this post.

Answer (score 1):

TCP does not allow the reader to determine what chunk sizes were sent. This information is not present on the write. Your application protocol must be able to deal with the fact that data can and will arrive in arbitrary chunks.

Comment: But how can i deal with "random" chunks? It's confusing that it is always only one byte which gets split apart. I can deal with one, but if it is more then one, i have no clue.

Comment: You probably need to parse the Websockets protocol. It has all the necessary information to tell everything apart.

Comment: So you mean that i need to wait til i received the hole data frame header, then read the bytes of data sent (length specified in the header) and read the next header....so on?

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly an old question but still I would like to contribute.

This problem occurs if you authenticate your stream with Tls(TLS 1 to be precise). If you followed microsoft guide (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream(v=vs.110).aspx) you probably use the following code to authenticate.

stream.AuthenticateAsServer(serverCertificate,false, SslProtocols.Tls, false);

As explained in https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3155464 due to a vulnerability in TLS 1 the stream will first get 1 byte followed by the rest of the bytes. To counter this you program needs to have a marker to determine when the message stops like .

Another way is to use TLS 1.2, You can use  stream.AuthenticateAsServer(serverCertificate,false, SslProtocols.Tls12, false);

Using this you will get full message.